# Outlook deletion emails through folders

Tags: python, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to go over deletion of emails using python. I'd like to delete over different folders for emails older than 30 days.
Issue i am facing: how to use this structure to make it go through different folders? e.g. not only folder 'Clients' but also 'Reports'

```
import datetime

import win32com.client as win32

import datetime as dt

outlook=win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')

o = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

accounts= win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts



root=outlook.Folders['sally_smith@gmail.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['New'].Folders['Clients']

inbox = root.Items

lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 30)

messages =  inbox.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] < '" +lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+"'")

for message in messages:

        message.Delete()
```

Comment: will all the folder be under `new` or `Clients`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to iterate over all subfolders of the `New` folder. So, you can iterate over all subfolders in the following way:

```
Dim objCurFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim subfolders as Outlook.Folders
subfolders=outlook.Folders['sally_smith@gmail.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['New'].Folders

For Each objCurFolder In subfolders
    Call ProcessCurrentFolder(objCurFolder)
Next
```

Where the separate method looks like that:

```
Private Sub ProcessCurrentFolder(ByVal objParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    '    Process each items in the folder
    For Each objMail In objParentFolder.Items
        '    Do your task here ...
    Next
End Sub
```